# How to change namespace in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I am using Symfony 2.6

My main bundle is AppBundle, so all namespaces within bundle look like this:

> AppBundle\DirectoryName

I would like to change all namespaces so that I end up with something like this:

> MyCompanyName\ProjectName\AppBundle\DirectoryName

========================================================

Next text shows what I have tried and the errors I had.

I have class StringUtilities:

```
<?php

namespace MyCompanyName\ProjectName\AppBundle\Utility;

class StringUtilities {

}
```

I am using StringUtilities here:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Auth;

use MyCompanyName\ProjectName\AppBundle\Utility\StringUtilities as SU;

class UserChecker extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker {
}
```

When running the application, I am getting this error:

> Attempted to load class "StringUtilities" from namespace
>   "MyCompanyName\ProjectName\AppBundle\Utility". Did you forget a "use"
>   statement for another namespace?

This is solved by adding this line in app/autoload.php

```
$loader->addPsr4('MyCompanyName\ProjectName\\', realpath(__DIR__.'/../src'));
```

Now I tried to change namespace of UseChecker class:

```
<?php

namespace MyCompanyName\ProjectName\AppBundle\Auth;

use MyCompanyName\ProjectName\AppBundle\Utility\StringUtilities as SU;

class UserChecker extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker {
}
```

And when I try to clear cache via console (php app/console cache:clear), I get this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>   The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Auth\UserChecker" to be
>   defined in file
>   "/home/damjan/Temp/licence-management/src/AppBundle/Auth/UserChecker.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not      in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

And when running the application in browser, I am getting this error:

> FatalErrorException in UserChecker.php line 0: Compile Error: Cannot
>   redeclare class MyCompanyName\ProjectName\AppBundle\Auth\UserChecker

Comment: I don't have a complete answer for you. Regarding the `Attempted to load class "StringUtilities" from namespace ` , you will be using `StringUtilities` inside the class. And not `SU` . Search and change to `SU` other than for use statement.

Comment: and `RuntimeException` errors are self explanatory. I think. Look more carefully .. What do you need to change ?

Comment: @HariKT SU is used in code and the problem is not there. I have errors like this two in any class of bundle if I try to change namespace.
As for RuntimeException from console, I posted all the text of the exception.

Comment: Remove the bundle registered on the AppKernel and fix the changes and add again the bundle. That should probably work.

Answer (score 2):

Change your autoload in composer, then run `composer dump-autoload`.

After that change your namespace bundle and your AppKernel and be happy.

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted, as this was the one step I failed to update when I renamed the default bundle to a custom name. Thank you holodoc!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it is not so easy and clean to go around the Sumfony rule:

> The bundle directory structure is used as the namespace hierarchy.

So I decided to rename appBundle also. Here is what I did:

- I made sub folder in src and named it `MyCompanyName`,
- and within it I moved AppBundle folder and renamed it to  `ProjectNameBundle`
- Than I used find replace to change all namespaces

  > AppBundle -> MyCompanyName\ProjectNameBundle

Be careful when changing because word AppBundle is not always in class path (namespace), it can be also part of directory path. For example, in config.yml i made this change:

I changed this:

```
orm:
    mappings:
        CompanyManagementBundle:
            type: annotation
            dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Entity
            prefix: AppBundle\Entity
            alias: AppBundle
```

Into this:

```
orm:
    mappings:
        CompanyManagementBundle:
            type: annotation
            dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/MyCompanyName/ProjectNameBundle/Entity
            prefix: MyCompanyName\ProjectNameBundle\Entity
            alias: ProjectNameBundle
```

In routing.yml I changed this:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Into this:

```
company_management:
    resource: "@ProjectNameBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

The point is: be careful while renaming.